# How to join a table & pull results for additional join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to pull all accounts for a group of employees by their SSN. While also pulling all accounts by their FA number (to include accounts they manage as well as accounts belonging to themselves).

This is the code i have so far. the SSN join is working, but I'm having trouble with the last join, connecting the emp_id to FA_emp_id

```
SELECT [Employee List].ID, 
[Employee List].FirstName, 
[Employee List].LastName, 
dbo_person.prsn_ssn_id, 
dbo_person.prsn_emp_id, 
Left([dbo_account_holder]![account_id],8) AS Account, 
dbo_account_holder.holder_nickname, 
dbo_account_holder.holder_reference_name
FROM ((([Employee List] LEFT JOIN dbo_person ON [Employee List].emp_id = dbo_person.prsn_emp_id) 
LEFT JOIN dbo_account_holder ON dbo_person.prsn_ssn_id = dbo_account_holder.holder_ssn_id) 
LEFT JOIN dbo_account ON dbo_account_holder.account_id = dbo_account.account_id)
LEFT JOIN  dbo_account ON [Employee List].emp_id = dbo_account.fa_emp_id
WHERE (((dbo_account.date_account_closed) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid unsuful  ()

and don't use left join table's columns in where condition  .. if  you do this  .. then this condtion work as an inner join 
add  the condition to the related on clause

```
SELECT [Employee List].ID, 
[Employee List].FirstName, 
[Employee List].LastName, 
dbo_person.prsn_ssn_id, 
dbo_person.prsn_emp_id, 
Left([dbo_account_holder]![account_id],8) AS Account, 
dbo_account_holder.holder_nickname, 
dbo_account_holder.holder_reference_name
FROM [Employee List] 
LEFT JOIN dbo_person ON [Employee List].emp_id = dbo_person.prsn_emp_id
LEFT JOIN dbo_account_holder ON dbo_person.prsn_ssn_id = dbo_account_holder.holder_ssn_id
LEFT JOIN dbo_account ON dbo_account_holder.account_id = dbo_account.account_id
LEFT JOIN  dbo_account ON [Employee List].emp_id = dbo_account.fa_emp_id 
                    AND  dbo_account.date_account_closed Is Null;
```